# how to count number of bit transitions in an unsigned int with java

Tags: java

I'm looking for a way of counting the number of bit transitions in an unsigned int.

If the int contains:  0000000000000000000001010

The number of transitions are: 4

If the int contains: 00000000000000000000001001

The number of transitions are:3

Comment: Which way are you using now? What time are we competing against?

Comment: i only want to know the way @Kayaman

Comment: This seems like homework. If you can do it in C, you should be able to figure it out in Java pretty easily.

Comment: @mttdbrd, the OP didn't claim an ability to do it in C, only that Google provided an answer to the problem already coded in C.

Comment: @KevinO there was a comment by the op a few minutes ago claiming that he knew how to do it in C.

Comment: yes you misunderstand @yitzih

Comment: please suggest me an algoritham...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The direct approach to this problem is to count the number of places where bit at the position `i` is different from bit at the position `i+1`. This can be done by XOR-ing the number with itself after a single right shift with sign extension:

```
Integer.bitCount(n ^ (n >> 1))
```

XOR operator `^` will put ones in all positions where bits at consecutive positions are different from each other. `Integer.bitCount` will complete the task by counting the number of ones.

Sign extension will ensure that there is no "phantom" transition from the most significant bit to zero, in cases when `n` is negative.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/4t1MKX)